# Python: how to avoid a loop for normalizing a list of list?

Tags: python, list, loops, numpy

I have a list `X` containing the data of `N` users. I want to have the relative frequency distribution of each user.

```
l1  = list()
for i in range(0,N):
    tmp = np.array(X[i])
    tmp = tmp[tmp < tr]
    tmp = np.histogram(tmp, x)
    l1.append(tmp[0]/sum(tmp[0]))
```

Is there any way to avoid this loop?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the loop?

Comment: If there is a way to make that operation over each list in inside the list `X` without doing that loop.

Comment: `np.sum` is likely faster than `sum`

Comment: Is `X` already a `np.array`?

Comment: Also, `np.histogram` takes a `density` keyword that lets you eliminate the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
def op(A):
    tmp = np.array(A)
    tmp = tmp[tmp < tr]
    tmp = np.histogram(tmp, x)
    return tmp[0]/sum(tmp[0])

# creates a generator
map(op, X)
# or, to get a list
l1 = list(map(op, X))
```

Comment: That sounds great. How can I pass values to `op` such as `tr` and `x`?

Comment: If all this code is inside another function and `tr` and `x` is in the function scope, it will just work. Otherwise, you will declare `def op(A, tr, x)` and call `map(lambda A: op(A, tr, x), X)`

Comment: That's very elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I got what you are asking for: How to avoid using `range` and also avoid appeding to `l1`. If this is your case you may use a generator, try this:

```
def iter_on_items(X):
    for item in X:
        tmp = np.array(item)
        tmp = tmp[tmp < tr]
        tmp = np.histogram(tmp, x)
        yield tmp[0]/sum(tmp[0])
```

Then you will need to consume it by doing this:

```
for result in iter_on_items(X):
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `map`? This is a builtin in function that accepts as input a function and an iterable and goes through applying the function to each element in the iterable. I've directly translated what you have above, but you could combine these into less `map` calls.

```
l1 = list(map(lambda a: np.array(a), X))
l1 = list(map(lambda a: a[a < tr], l1))
l1 = list(map(lambda a: np.histogram(a, X), l1))
l1 = list(map(lambda a: a[0]/sum(a[0]), l1))
```